# Compiled C Program Wont Run Under My uid But Will Run As Root

Tags: c, gcc, selinux, fips, rhel8

System: RHEL8   4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64
Selinux: Enabled
FIPS:    Enabled

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  fprintf( stdout, "Running test Program...\r\n" );
}
```

Compile:
gcc test.c -o test

Run Program:
./test
-bash: ./test: Operation not permitted
It doesn't work.

List Directory:
$ ls -l
total 24
-rwx------. 1 dev dev 18088 Aug  9 13:01 test
-rw-r--r--. 1 dev dev    95 Aug  9 13:00 test.c

List File Attributes:
-------------------- ./test.c
-------------------- ./test

Mounted Partition:
There is -> no <-  "noexec"  set.

Run as root:
sudo ./test
Running test Program...
It works running as root.

What am I missing here?
I have read, write, and execute permission for this file.

Comment: `test` is not a good name for a program (it is already used by another command: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/test.htm)

Comment: Check /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure to see if the execution was blocked

Comment: What user are you when you try to run it?  The program is executable only by user "dev".  Are you that user when you try to run it?

Comment: I suppose it's possible there's a permissions issue with a shared library such as `/lib/libc.so`.

Comment: @Ranieri ->  Thanks for the insight!  Renamed to simpleTest.c.   Still didn't work.

Comment: @dbush -> Checked it,  nothing.

Comment: @Steve ->  trying to run as user 'dev'

Comment: Do you have fapolicyd running?

Comment: I wonder if it's significant that the error message is "Operation not permitted"?  If it were a permissions issue, I'd expect "Permission denied".  But I can't find an errno value for "Operation not permitted" just now, or a corresponding failure reason at `man 2 execve`.

Comment: Try copying your program to another location and running it there — `cp simpleTest "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}"; "$TMPDIR/simpleTest"`.  If that works, the problem is associated with the directory you're compiling/running it in — or in a directory above that.  If that fails too, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I suspect that selinux may be outright prohibiting the running of programs not in "approved" bin directories, or something.  I found some tips at https://www.mysysadmintips.com/linux/servers/587-find-if-permission-denied-error-is-caused-by-selinux that might be useful to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the owner (chown) or the permissions (chmod) of the executable and/or the directory it is in. Maybe something is wrong with it.